# CQRS Page View Counts

Tags: cqrs

In CQRS, how can I persist information about view counts? e.g. user visits a particular page x times

The simple answer is that the Read Model updates its own tables and increments the count.

But what if we need to re-build our Read Model from the Write Model? We would loose all the view count statistics.

Should the Read Model call the Write Model and tell it that a page has been viewed?

The problem with this is that the Write Model now has too much information about the Read Models implementation i.e. the Write Model should not know how a read model is displaying pages. It should be decoupled from all Read Models.

How do people implement this in their systems?

Comment: This is really a question for http://Programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You queue each audit of a read onto the command queue, just as per any other command. This will then be written to the applicable write store, which will (eventually) be projected back into the original read store. If the readstore has a high frequency of reads (which it should, since that's why you chose CQRS :), you'll probably want to batch the updates to limit the frequency of writes.

Comment: @Mgetz do you want to write up your response into a full answer with some explanation? This will assist me and others going forward

Comment: @StuartLC could you provide an example in an answer? Im struggling because i can't see how i would model this on the write side. Calling the command pageXHasBeenViewed() seems like a smell to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data that you might wish to track or store is done via the **Write Model** you should not break the principal of CQRS just because something may seem trivial or to be a break of concerns.

In this particular case you're introducing a *Data View Tracking* domain, it doesn't need to know where its data is coming from.

If you're using EventSourcing as your data store you can short circuit the whole thing and issue a `DataViewedEvent` when the page request is received.

The command would be something like dataViewed(obj) where obj can be anything the read model wants. The obj is then attached to DataViewedEvent.

This means that when the read model receives a DataViewedEvent, it can look at the obj type saved in the event and only pass it to a handler that cares about that obj type.

e.g.

Page X is viewed. Calls dataViewed(PageXViewed) command. Read Model receives dataViewed event, looks at the object stored inside it, passed PageXViewed to the handler that cares about that page view.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you pull into a sort of Sub Write model? As the data is only of interest to a specific Read Model. For example you could have multiple Read Model subscribers presenting info and pages in different ways and requiring different stats to be stored. If the 'main' write model had to handle this it could become a bit messy

Comment: @Gaz_Edge that's why I would use EventSourcing, then my write model becomes extremely simple and I wouldn't care. It would just be another event in the stream. But no I wouldn't go out of my way to break it out other than to have a dedicated service as it's really its own domain and should be treated as such.

Comment: Yeah i use event sourcing. I think a better way may be to use a command DataViewed(Obj) which takes a serialised object from the Read Model and just adds it to the event store. On deserialisation the read model can check the type of the object and then only send it to the views that care about it. Otherwise you'd end up having every view checking every UriViewedEvent

Comment: @Gaz_Edge that depends on how you want to use the data and what the domain entity is. The beauty of Eventsourcing is you can transform the data as you like. The other downside of a `UriViewedEvent` is that URIs can and do change for SEO

Comment: agree, but I think the more general dataViewed(Obj) is better as your implementation assumes use of a URI. With the more general method the write model is then decoupled from the read models and the read models can add anything they want into dataViewed(Obj) without changes needed in the write model.

Comment: @DennisTraub I respectfully disagree, particularly with an event sourcing architecture as the backing store.

Comment: @DennisTraub the question was about a specific CQRS implementation. If you are going to stick to CQRS then my answer holds true. If you're going to do whatever you want then this question is irrelevant. My point was that if you are you shouldn't destroy your read model by adding write to it.